# PWA in iOS 12 no longer re-executing Javascript when re-opening app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA which essentially re-directs the user to the messages app on open using Javascript. With the roll-out of iOS 12 and changes to PWAs, the webpage no longer re-initializes and executes the Javascript when it is re-opened or when it re-gains focus. Instead, it now loads the previously saved state and won't re-execute the Javascript.

Does anyone have any ideas around this? Can I force Javascript execution every time the PWA has focus? Can I force the page to re-initialize on load?

Sample code below:

```html
<html manifest="ios/scripts/offline.manifest">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>SMS</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="SMS">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />


<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="ios/img/Icon-60x60@3x.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="ios/img/LaunchImage-1125@3x~iphoneX-portrait_1125x2436.png" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)">
</head>

<body>
<script>
        if (window.navigator.standalone) {
            document.write('<a id="url" href="sms:1111111111" name="url"></a>');
            var e = document.getElementById('url');
            var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            ev.initEvent('click', true, true);
            e.dispatchEvent(ev);
        }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am also encountering the same issue after opening mail app with <a> tag. I'm stuck at the blank screen. Anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Here is what I did to force PWA to execute javascript at start:

1. Register page visibility event in your javascript that is embedded
   between  tags.
2. Within the event handler of page visibility event, execute javascript that you want to execute when subsequently open PWA.

Any time PWA is opened, it will trigger page visibility event and execute your script.

Example: in your html file:

```
<script>
registerPageVisibility()
</script>
```

```js
function registerPageVisibility() {
   
    let hidden;
    let visibilityChange;
    if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
        hidden = 'hidden';
        visibilityChange = 'visibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== 'undefined') {
        hidden = 'msHidden';
        visibilityChange = 'msvisibilitychange';
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
        hidden = 'webkitHidden';
        visibilityChange = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
    }
    window.document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, () => {
        if (!document[hidden]) {
            //put your script here and it will be execute everytime when PWA is opened.
            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Issue was with using the document.write function as the page would be re-written and cleared after execution.